# Restrict delete collection operation in SOLR

Tags: solr, solr8

i have 2 SOLR Users- UserA and UserB. I want to restrict the collection access for some of the SOLR collections so that only UserA can access those collections. I ran the below commands to achieve it:

**Bind User role with Username**

```
curl -u <<admin_user>>:<<admin_user_password>> -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{​​​​​​​
   "set-user-role" : {​​​​​​​
                      "userA": ["build","my-rule"]}​​​​​​​
}​​​​​​​'
http://<<solr-host>>:<<solr-port>>/solr/admin/authorization
```

**Update collection permission**

```
    curl --user <<admin_user>>:<<admin_user_password>>  -H 'content-type:application/json' -d '{
"set-permission": {"name":"my-collection-rules","collection": ["collection", "collection2"],
 "path":"/*","role": "my-rule"}}' http://<<solr-host>>:<<solr-port>>/solr/admin/authorization
```

I observed that after running these commands, only UserA was able to access data from said collections using select handler, UserB is getting 403 error while querying the data and this is expected. But UserB is still able to delete the collections. Is there a way we can even restrict the delete access as well to UserA so that UserB is not able to delete collections belonging to userA?

Comment: Any administrative tasks go through the `/admin/collections` endpoint. You should add custom rules for that endpoint as well, and not only for the collection specific endpoints (which gets served under `/collections`).

Comment: Do you have any example of how custom rules for /admin/collections can help restrict access to specific collections? i tried below command and it did not work:

curl --user <<admin_user>>:<<admin_user_password>>  -H 'content-type:application/json' -d '{"set-permission": {"name":"my-collection-rules2","params":{"action":["DELETE"]},"collection": ["collection", "collection2"], "path":"/admin/collections","role": "my-rule"}}' http://<<solr-host>>:<<solr-port>>/solr/admin/authorization

Comment: As far as I know you can't limit the administrative calls to a specific collections - they're about creating, removing and changing system information about the collections. But I haven't used the feature in a long time, so it might be possible depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: ok, so basically it's a technical feasibility issue.

Comment: You should be able to limit the `name` parameter together with the `action` parameter as shown in the custom permissions example: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_7/rule-based-authorization-plugin.html#custom-permissions - that way you'll only give access to a specific action for a specific collection for a specific user. If all the methods in the collection api uses `name` to identify collections (I haven't checked), you should be able to let a user do all tasks regarding a specific collection by limiting on that param.